# Get results only when a single column doesn't exist more than once

Tags: t-sql

Alright so in this case distinct doesn't work because it's not a single column modifier but entire result modifier, not sure really on what to use, I'm doing adventureworks exercises:

Query I've done until now:

```
select SalesOrderID, UnitPrice
from SalesOrderDetail
inner join Product
on SalesOrderDetail.ProductID = Product.ProductID
```

that's the original statement without the "distinct" part of it, these are the results I get, as you can see I get multiple repeated ID's, and the question asks me to get just "single item orders", meaning orders that only contain one detail

```
SalesOrderID    UnitPrice
71774    356.90
71774    356.90
71776    63.90
71780    218.45
71780    461.69
71780    113.00
71780    818.70
71780    323.99
71780    149.87
71780    809.76
71780    1376.99
71780    158.43
71780    1391.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try aggregating here by `SalesOrderID`, and then retain the minimum the unit price:

```
SELECT
    sod.SalesOrderID,
    MIN(p.UnitPrice) AS UnitPrice
FROM SalesOrderDetail sod
INNER JOIN Product p
    ON sod.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY
    sod.SalesOrderID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1;
```

This works because for sales orders having only one product, the minimum unit price is coincident with the one and only unit price.

Note that I am assuming that every sales order has at least one product record associated with it.  An inner join would filter off sales orders with no products.

Comment: Makes sense, didn't even think about filtering out the results with no products but it actually probably should be required too, accepted yours cause of the detailed answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Select OD.SalesOrderID, UnitPrice
from SalesOrderDetail as OD
inner join Product as P
on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
inner join (select SalesOrderId
from SalesOrderDetail 
GROUP BY SalesOrderId
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1) as OneOD on OneOD.SalesOrderId = OD.SalesOrderId
```

This should get the desired results. Thanks..